# I can't seem to display my query results on page?

Tags: php, mysql

First of all I'm fairly new to php but I have the rough idea of it. I have literally been looking for hours into days into weeks to solve this (what I'd think to be simple function) and I hate having to resort to bothering others but I'm sorry as I genuinly can't understand why it isn't working.

I will give the basic layout of what is going on and I'll use password=password username=username etc to demonstrate:

```
   <div id="something>
   <?php

   define ('HOSTNAME', 'hostname');
   define ('USERNAME', 'username');
   define ('PASSWORD', 'password');
   define ('DATABASE_NAME', 'databasename');

   $db = mysql_connect(HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD) or die ('I cannot connect to MySQL.');

   mysql_select_db(DATABASE_NAME);

   $query = "SELECT ImageName , ImagePath FROM Thumbnails";

   $result = mysql_query($query);

   $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)

   echo $row['ImageName'];
   echo $row['ImagePath'];

   mysql_close();
   ?>

   </div>
```

And, of cource there is a table within the database called 'Thumbnails' and inside that are numorous rows 2 of which are 'ImageName' and 'ImagePath' which currently contain 1 field each being 'example' and 'example.jpg'. I have tried experimenting with ('"]. and all sorts to get it working but none of which work. Again I'm sorry for being a bother and I'm sure I should look into the basics first but I'd persume this would be the basics hmm, well thanks in advance. p.s I also tried with the different db config setup and lots of different layouts:

```
 $hostname='hostname';
 $username='username';
 $password='password';
 $dbname='database';
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Oh i see, But this would of worked when it was maintained? Sorry for my ignorance I find it hard to keep track when google leads me to posts 5-6 years ago. I geuss I can start scavenging from here now so, thanks for the reply I would never of known.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should put a quotation mark after 'something'.
Second you forgot the semicolon after the row-variable line.

Next to that I'm pretty sure you should put it in a while-loop like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['ImageName'];
    echo $row['ImagePath'];
}
```

Comment: Add to that, shouldn't it be mysql_fetch_assoc?

Comment: Hmm, sorry but still nothing is showing up. But, don't worry thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You must put the `mysql_fetch_array` function in a loop

```
// ...   

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['ImageName'];
    echo $row['ImagePath'];
    echo PHP_EOL;
}

// ...
```